# Singly Linked List: newNode function doesn't point to next Node

Tags: c, linked-list, int, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am currently experimenting with singly-linked-list in C. I have written a 
`newNode` function to create a Node and a `printNodes` function to print out all nodes - it looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node 
{
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
}; 

void printNodes(struct Node *current_node)
{
  while(current_node != NULL)
  {
    printf("Node is: %d\n", current_node->data);
    current_node = current_node->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int number_1 = 2;
  int number_2 = 3;
  int number_3 = 4;

  struct Node *head;
  struct Node *second;
  struct Node *third;

  head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));  
  second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
  third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  head->data = number_1;      
  head->next = second; 

  second->data = number_2;      
  second->next = third; 

  third->data = number_3;     
  third->next = NULL; 

  printNodes(head);

}
```

output is correctly:

```
Node is: 2
Node is: 3 
Node is: 4
```

Now I wanted to write a function `newNode` which is used to create a new node, I changed my code to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node 
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *newNode(int number_x, struct Node *nextnode)
{
    struct Node *tmp_node;

    tmp_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tmp_node->data = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tmp_node->data = number_x;
    tmp_node->next = nextnode;

    return tmp_node;
}   

void printNodes(struct Node *current_node)
{
    while(current_node != NULL)
    {
        printf("Node is: %d\n", current_node->data);
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number_1 = 2;
    int number_2 = 3;
    int number_3 = 4;

    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *second;
    struct Node *third;

    head = newNode(number_1, second);
    second = newNode(number_2, third);
    third = newNode(number_3, NULL);

    printNodes(head);

}
```

After compiling I first get this warning message:

```
test.c:16:20: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion 
assigning to 'int' from 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]
tmp_node->data = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And the output looks like this:

```
Node is: 2
```

It only shows the Node `head`, I guess there is something wrong with `next` pointing 
(e.g. `head->next = second`), but what is wrong? I am unable to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Fyi, ask yourself what the value of `second` is in `main` when you do this: `head = newNode(number_1, second);` ? If your answer is "i dunno", you're on the same page as your program, because it doesn't either. Pointers hold *values* (which happened to be addresses). Without assigning them properly(in this case building your list *backwards*), you're loading your structure `next` members with indeterminate values, the later evaluation of which invokes *undefined behavior*. Regarding your error, why are you assigning a memory address to your `int` data member ?

Comment: your error is unrelated to the problem, but it is a problem as you're leaking memory - `tmp_node->data` is an `int` and doesn't need memory allocating for it...especially as you overwrite it's contents on the line that follows

Comment: @WhozCraig `second`doesn't have a value i guess, it is just a node that has been initialized, as I want then that `head` points to `second`with node (as in ex1).. So I guess the input of second is empty?

Comment: @s.r. put another way. If I write `int x; printf("%d\n", x);` what would you expect to be printed? The only right answer here is "we don't know what x is, so we have no idea." The same is true for your `second` and `third` pointers in your second code list. They have not been given determinate values at the time you're using them, so using their values  as input to your function makes no sense. Now, think about what would happen if you build your nodes *backwards* (third, then second, then head) using the otherwise-same calls you have now, but in reverse order. Just think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
tmp_node->data = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); /* remove this statement */
```

`data` is a member of `struct Node` & that's a integer, for this separately you don't have to allocate memory. you have already allocated for complete structure here

```
tmp_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); /* this is enough */
```

Also here

```
head = newNode(number_1, second);
```

what is `second` ? It should be initialized with `NULL` like

```
struct Node *second = NULL;
```

then only in `newNode()` function `tmp_node->next` assigned with correct value

```
tmp_node->next = nextnode; /* now nextnode contains NULL, that's correct */
```

Or you can make it like below

```
head = newNode(number_1, NULL);
second = newNode(number_2, head);
third = newNode(number_3, second);
```

and then while calling `printNodes()` pass the `third` instead of `head`. For e.g

```
printNodes(third);
```

Sample code :

```
struct Node  {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *newNode(int number_x, struct Node *nextnode) {
    struct Node *tmp_node;
    tmp_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tmp_node->data = number_x;
    tmp_node->next = nextnode;
    return tmp_node;
}

void printNodes(struct Node *current_node) {
    while(current_node != NULL) {
        printf("Node is: %d\n", current_node->data);
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int number_1 = 2;
    int number_2 = 3;
    int number_3 = 4;

    struct Node *head = NULL;
    struct Node *second = NULL;
    struct Node *third = NULL;

    head = newNode(number_1, NULL);
    second = newNode(number_2, head);
    third = newNode(number_3, second);
    printNodes(third);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whilst your answer is pointing out a problem - it doesn't answer the question being asked

Comment: Thanks @ChrisTurner for pointing. I guess it's works now. My immediate reply was about OP's warning message about `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

First, the warning (which should be treated as an error, fyi) you are seeing is not related to your overall problem, but it is nonetheless important. It is both improper, and leaks memory, and has the vague appearance of testing spaghetti. In case you've never done it, an old-school kitchen technique to see if the pasta is "done" is to take a strand from the pot and literally throw it at the wall to see if it sticks. This seemingly extraneous line of code looks like just that; like you threw something at the wall to see if it stuck:

This:

```
tmp_node->data = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // DELETE THIS
```

shouldn't even be in your code *at all*;  the succeeding line does what should be done, namely this:

```
tmp_node->data = number_x; // KEEP THIS
```

---

**Wiring A Linked List**

While the prior diatribe is concerning, it isn't what is delivering your unenviable position of not wiring your list correctly. That is a problem all unto itself.  Consider the following:

```
struct Node *head;      // indeterminate
struct Node *second;    // indeterminate
struct Node *third;     // indeterminate
```

In the first two `newNode` calls you're passing indeterminate pointer values to what will eventually be the newly allocated node `next` pointers. This is significant. My reversing the build order you can get behavior you seek.

```
third = newNode(number_3, NULL);    // third is set, next points to NULL
second = newNode(number_2, third);  // second it set, next points to third
head = newNode(number_1, second);   // head is set, next points to second
```

Obviously it's not ideal to have to do this, but to just learn how things are wired this is one way to do it. Another would be to actually assign to the next members directly. For example:

```
head = newNode(number_1, NULL); 
head->next = newNode(number_2, NULL);
head->next->next = newNode(number_3, NULL);
```

This works as well, but again, isn't ideal. Would you really want to do this for building a linked list of a hundred nodes ?

**Forward Chaining A Linked List**

There *is* a very succinct way to build a ascending linked list without having to do the above.  It is called *forward-chaining* and utilizes a pointer-to-pointer, which initially points to the head pointer itself (which is initially NULL):

```
struct Node *head = NULL;
struct Node **pp = &head; // points to a pointer, initially the head pointer
```

With the above, we can chain together a list of however many elements you want. A hundred ? no problem:

```
for (int i=1; i<=100; ++i)
{
    // allocate a new node, storing the address at whatever pointer
    // is being addressed by the pointer-to-pointer pp. Initially it
    // will be the `head` pointer variable.

    *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
    (*pp)->data = i;

    // move pp to point to the next pointer of the node we just added
    pp = &(*pp)->next;
}
*pp = NULL; // terminate the list


printNodes(head);
```

This is just one way to build linked lists. There are many others (doing it recursively, for example, is not uncommon when studying recursion in school). But it is probably the simplest, an near-certainly the fastest.

Anyway, that was longer than I intended, but I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WhozCraig for clarifying.

As he mentioned, the `second` node doesn't know what his input is.
To break it down, the same happens if you write something like this: 
`int num; printf("%d",num)`

The programm doesn't know what's the input since there hasn't been an input initialized.

The same thing happens with my programm, there has been no node initalized so the programm doesn't know where `next-node` is.
But if I write the programm backwards, the programm does now understand what the value is and can work with it:

```
    //use it backwards
    third = newNode(number_3, NULL);
    second = newNode(number_2, third);
    head = newNode(number_1, second);
```

Now, the output is correctly:

```
Node is: 2
Node is: 3
Node is: 4
```

thanks for helping,
cheers.